# Compiling Basic C-Language CUDA code in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, cuda, nvidia

I've spent a lot of time setting up the CUDA toolchain on a machine running Ubuntu Linux (11.04).  The rig has two NVIDIA Tesla GPUs, and I'm able to compile and run test programs from the NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK such as deviceQuery, deviceQueryDrv, and bandwidthTest.

My problems arise when I try to compile basic sample programs from books and online sources.  I know you're supposed to compile with NVCC, but I get compile errors whenever I use it.  Basically any sort of include statement involving CUDA libraries gives a missing file/library error.  An example would be:

```
#include <cutil.h>
```

Do I need some sort of makefile to direct the compiler to these libraries or are there additional flags I need to set when compiling with NVCC?

I followed these guides:

http://hdfpga.blogspot.com/2011/05/install-cuda-40-on-ubuntu-1104.html   http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf

Comment: How are you building the SDK samples? Are there any compiler flags listed there that you aren't using with NVCC?

Comment: I was building with "nvcc test.cu -o test", essentially.  perreal's solution worked for me, though.

Comment: Spoke too soon, I compiled a different sample program that included cutil.h and I got the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix the include problems add the cuda include directory to your compilation options (assuming it is /usr/local/cuda/include):

```
nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib test.cu -o test
```

Comment: This worked!  I was able to compile this program from my home folder:

http://www.resultsovercoffee.com/2011/01/our-first-cuda-c-program.html

I got one warning that didn't seem to affect my success:

"/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudart.so when searching for -lcudart"

Comment: I take that back, sorry.  I spoke too soon, I compiled a different sample program that included cutil.h and I got the same error.
nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib matrixmul.cu -o matrixmul

matrixmul.cu:6: fatal error: cutil.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated

Comment: `cutil.h` is included in the SDK, so you also need to add `-I/CUDA_SDK_PATH/C/common/inc` to the nvcc options

Comment: That works for me.  Thanks, and sorry again for not understanding the first time.

Answer (score 1):

`cutil` is not part of the CUDA toolkit. It's part of the CUDA SDK. So, assuming you have followed the instructions and you have added the PATH and LIB directories to your environment variables you still need to point to the CUDA SDK includes and libraries directories.

In order to include that lib manually you must pass the paths to the compiler:

```
nvcc -I/CUDA_SDK_PATH/C/common/inc -L/CUDA_SDK_PATH/C/lib ...
```

Although I personally prefer not to use the CUDA SDK libraries, you probably will find easier start a project from a CUDA SDK example.

Comment: This also worked, and it didn't throw the warning that I mentioned in perreal's answer.

I'm new to stackoverflow - perhaps this is out of scope, but any reason why you don't like to use the CUDA SDK libs?  I'm just getting started with CUDA so I'm keeping an eye out for tips.

Comment: Again, I spoke too soon.  This is what I get when I build using this command line string:

nvcc -I/CUDA_SDK_PATH/C/common/inc -L/CUDA_SDK_PATH/C/lib matrixmul.cu -o matrixmul
matrixmul.cu:6: fatal error: cutil.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Feel very foolish - I was leaving CUDA_SDK_PATH instead of substituting my own.  It works now, thank you.

Comment: Regarding to the use of the SDK libs, I recommend search in stackoverflow. If you dont find an answer then you may ask a new question.